# baobab missing hundreds of gigabytes

Tags: filesystem, disk

The following shows the result of:

```
sudo baobab
```

For some reason there are about 400GB missing, and all root directories are being scanned.
How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: It is showing used/filled space of a 1 TB drive.  Do you have over 800GBs of data and 400 are not showing?

Comment: Thanks @crip659, I'm not sure how >915GB filled on root comes from the <480GB worth of listed sub-directories.  What I can tell you is that the 435GB of contents calculated by baobab + 90GB free space is approximately 2x the size of my 256GB swap file.  Almost like there is a 'ghost' swap file the size of my existing swap file

Comment: Try opening up disks or gparted and see your free space.  Make sure you check your / partition.  Baobab also shows my / full on top in red box, but have at least 1/3 free.  It also /home as full, but only have a little bit of data in it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into what seems to be the same problem - baobab does not recognize swap files whether they are in use, or not.  On my system, there were 2 swapfiles (I only knew about 1) and only one was active - I found the problem using du.

Sorry for the late response - but I hope it helps others that stumble here.